# Powerpivot connection refresh opens source file

Tags: excel, vba, connection, pivot, powerpivot

With the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Model.Refresh 
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

I want to refresh the Powerpivot connection. The unintentional side effect is that it (sometimes) opens the source file. Any idea how this is possible? I have multiple excel files but only this file has this issue.

Please advise.

Regards Bobby

Comment: Anyone? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is there someone who can help me??

Comment: Is the data being loaded via Power Query or directly though the Power Pivot editor?  Since I have seen the behavior when the import is created within Power Pivot of it opening the source file when someone else is in the source file.

Comment: The data is being loaded through vba with code: activeworkbook.model.refresh. When I open the PowerPivot window it refreshes normally.